# Migrating from Grunt to Gulp using grunt2gulp

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, gulp

I am trying to migrate from Grunt to Gulp using grunt2gulp.js. In the output gulpfile.js, I got an error: 'Please remove "time-grunt" from the Gruntfile.js'. On encountering this error, I commented the following code in my Gruntfile.js

```
//require('time-grunt')(grunt);
```

On reproducing the gulpfile.js, I am still getting the same error. Any idea how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You really need remove the line and try it again. 
For me works.

Look :

```
cmacedo-OSX:Simple-Hello-World-Cloud-App camilamacedo$ /usr/local/opt/nvm/versions/node/v4.4.7/bin/grunt2gulp Gruntfile.js
Please remove "time-grunt" from the Gruntfile

cmacedo-OSX:Simple-Hello-World-Cloud-App camilamacedo$ /usr/local/opt/nvm/versions/node/v4.4.7/bin/grunt2gulp Gruntfile.js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var concurrent = require('gulp-concurrent');
var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');
var env = require('gulp-env');
var nodeInspector = require('gulp-node-inspector');
var nodemon = require('gulp-nodemon');
var open = require('gulp-open');
var plato = require('gulp-plato');
var shell = require('gulp-shell');
var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');


gulp.task('watch', function () {
  gulp.watch('gruntfile.js', [ /* dependencies */ ]);
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
  gulp.watch('application.js', [ /* dependencies */ ]);
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
  gulp.watch('lib/**/*.js', [ /* dependencies */ ]);
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
  gulp.watch('test/**/*.js', [ /* dependencies */ ]);
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
  gulp.watch('public/views/**', [ /* dependencies */ ]);
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
  gulp.watch('app/views/**', [ /* dependencies */ ]);
});

gulp.task('nodemon', function () {
  return gulp
    .src('[object Object]')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dev'))
  ;
});

gulp.task('concurrent', function () {
  return gulp
    .src('nodemon,watch')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('serve'))
  ;
});

gulp.task('concurrent', function () { // WARNING: potential duplicate task
  return gulp
    .src('node-inspector,shell:debug,open:debug')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('debug'))
  ;
});

gulp.task('env', function () {
  return gulp
    .src('[object Object]')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('local'))
  ;
});

gulp.task('node-inspector', function () {
  return gulp
    .src('[object Object]')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dev'))
  ;
});

gulp.task('shell', function () {
  return gulp
    .src('[object Object]')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('debug'))
  ;
});

gulp.task('shell', function () { // WARNING: potential duplicate task
  return gulp
    .src('[object Object]')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('unit'))
  ;
});

gulp.task('shell', function () { // WARNING: potential duplicate task
  return gulp
    .src('[object Object]')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('accept'))
  ;
});

gulp.task('shell', function () { // WARNING: potential duplicate task
  return gulp
    .src('[object Object]')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('coverage_unit'))
  ;
});

gulp.task('shell', function () { // WARNING: potential duplicate task
  return gulp
    .src('[object Object]')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('coverage_accept'))
  ;
});

gulp.task('open', function () {
  return gulp
    .src('[object Object]')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('debug'))
  ;
});

gulp.task('open', function () { // WARNING: potential duplicate task
  return gulp
    .src('[object Object]')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('platoReport'))
  ;
});

gulp.task('plato', function () {
  return gulp
    .src('undefined')
    .pipe(gulp.dest(''))
  ;
});

gulp.task('jshint', function () {
  return gulp
    .src('*.js,lib/**/*.js,test/**/*.js')
    .pipe(jshint())
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
  ;
});

gulp.task('test', ["jshint","shell:unit","shell:accept"]);

gulp.task('unit', ["jshint","shell:unit"]);

gulp.task('accept', ["env:local","shell:accept"]);

gulp.task('coverage', ["shell:coverage_unit","shell:coverage_accept"]);

gulp.task('coverage-unit', ["shell:coverage_unit"]);

gulp.task('coverage-accept', ["env:local","shell:coverage_accept"]);

gulp.task('analysis', ["plato:src","open:platoReport"]);

gulp.task('serve', ["env:local","concurrent:serve"]);

gulp.task('debug', ["env:local","concurrent:debug"]);

gulp.task('default', ["serve"]);

cmacedo-OSX:Simple-Hello-World-Cloud-App camilamacedo$
```